# What is the difference between plus and plusAssign in operator overloading of kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I know there are some difference between `plus` and `plusAssign`, the latter can't return anything, but I find that the `plus` can achieve what `plusAssign` do.

A `Point` class overloads `plus` and return a new `Point`.

```
 data class Point(var x: Int, var y: Int)
{
    operator fun plus(other: Point): Point
    {
        return Point(x + other.x, y + other.y)
    }
}
```

A `Point` class overloads `plusAssign` but do not return a new `Point`.

```
data class Point(var x: Int, var y: Int)
{
    operator fun plusAssign(other: Point): Unit
    {
       this.x+=other.x
        this.y+=other.y
    }
}
```

But I find it can also be achieved like this:

```
data class Point(var x: Int, var y: Int)
{
    operator fun plus(other: Point): Point
    {
       this.x+=other.x
        this.y+=other.y

        return this;
    }
}
```

So, I can't find something make `plusAssign` special, is there anything `plusAssign` can do but `plus` can't?

Comment: Sure, you can modify `a` when I do `a + b`, but I totally expect you NOT to do that because it's insane.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you are talking about overloading, you have full control of what the function do, even that you completely swap the implementation of `plus` and `plusAssign` (not possible in Kotlin), or even `minus`. Although you are allowed to do that, it is not suggested.

In general, `plus` function should be a **pure** function (function with no side effect) which concatenates two objects and return the concatenated result. It does not change the value of the object. `plusAssign` should be a **mutating** function which concatenates the left-hand-side operand with the right-hand-side operand. It mutates the object (left-hand-side operand) instead of passing the result back.